# a copy of index.cshtml was found in App_Web_*.dll, but the correct source code is different from the version built into App_Web_*.dll,

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, dll

Hi I've been stuck on this problem all day and was hoping for some guidance.

The file index.cshtml is within my Views folder, the code is within that page. the DLL is not directly referenced in my project referrences.

I've tried the following things:

```
-Clean and rebuild Project
-delete bin and obj directory
-removed tmp .net directories:
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files
- Unticked "Only build startup projects and dependencies on Run,
- Cleared SymbolCache here \AppData\Local\Temp\SymbolCache
-Removed and re-added the view from the project
- Check the project configuration properties to ensure its set to build
- ensure its in debug mode.
- run through localIIS web server and IISExpress
```

I'm all out of ideas. Even after i clear the Temp asp.net directories they still get re-populated with the Web_App_*.dll and the pdb file. the timestamp is correct and both pdb file and dll file were created simultaniously.

What else could be going wrong?

Many thanks

Comment: Have you checked to make sure the "real" `index.cshtml` is in the standard Views folder?  If it isn't have you configured a new view engine to include the real location?

Comment: I dont know exactly what you mean by the real index.cshtml. I have a Views folder, within it is another folder and within that is my index.cshtml so the url is website.com/folder/. i also dont know what you mean by configuring a new view engine

Answer (score 3):

This same issue plagued me today. I noticed a breakpoint not hit in **Index.cshtml** razor because **source code is different than in App_Web*.dll**.  This occurred after I switched from IIS Express to local IIS.

To resolve, I did these things

- Exit Visual Studio
- Restart application pool and site in IIS;
- exit IIS Express process and e.g. use "C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\appcmd.exe"
- clear C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files
- clear C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files
- clear .\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WebsiteCache
- clear .\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files
- Clean Rebuild